# Least divisor of a number starting from a certain threshold

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I'm going through `The Haskell Road to Logic, Math, and Programming` and for the first problem I am already really confused. This function LDF is supposed to be:

> LDF, for the least divisor starting from a given threshold k, with k <= n.

However, I feel like it does something else, since as implemented

`ldf 8 16` will return `8` but `ldf 7 16 will return 16`.

Something must be wrong, or as I fear I am missing out on something. This is how the book implements the function.

```
ldf :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
ldf k n | divides k n = k
        |k^2>n =n
        | otherwise = ldf (k+1) n
```

I modified the second line to be:

`k > n = n`

and now I get the results I expect, but I just want to make sure I am not missing something.

Comment: I suspect it is intended to be a helper function used to find the prime factors of a number, to be called only with arguments satisfying a strong assumption, namely that the second argument ($n$) is known to have no prime factors smaller than the first ($k$, which must be $> 1$). It is of course also possible that the author(s?) just screwed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [by Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473040/least-divisor-of-a-number-starting-from-a-certain-threshold#comment1018527_473040), the second clause is only correct if we know that no divisor of $n$ is smaller than $k$.

If we do not have this information, we can do a bit better than to replace it with:

`| k > n = n`

by noting that $2$ is the smallest prime number, so that no divisor of $n$ can be strictly between $\dfrac n 2$ and $n$. Therefore, a correct replacement for the second clause would be:

`| 2*k > n = n`